# Modifying jQuery plugin Columnizer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify the jQuery Columnizer  plugin to create a mega menu effect on a navigation menu that loads dynamic/managed content. The business rules are that the menu items should be defaulting to 2 columns (they are currently defaulting to 1), and if the height of the columns exceeds a height - in this case, I'm putting 400px - then create a new column. If it exceeds 800px then create a 4th column.

I modified the source of the Columnizer plugin which is shown here (I commented my code with //jvirgo): http://screenquill.com/jquerytest/autocolumn.js and on this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/P4wVV/

my modification is here: 
// jvirgo

```
if (targetHeight() > 100) {
numCols == 3;
}
if (targetHeight() > 200) {
numCols == 4;
}
```

however, this completely breaks functionality of columnizer. Do I have incorrect syntax or am I targeting the wrong variable for height?

Answer (score 1):

I think the variable you would like to be modifying is "options.columns", not maxHeight. I would probably put your modifications just after the maxHeight variable is set, a few lines above where you are now. This is untested:

```
var maxHeight = $(this).height();
// mod
if (maxHeight > 100) { options.columns = 2 }
if (maxHeight > 200) { options.columns = 4 }
// end mod
var $cache = $('<div></div>');
```

You could also call columnizer from within your own function which measures the height and leaves columnizer unmodified (possibly for use elsewhere within the site):

```
$('div.subBody').each(function() {
  var h = $(this).height();
  if (h > 100) {
    var c = h > 200 ? 4 : 2;
    $(this).columnize({columns:c});
  }
 });
```

Not sure this is the best possible code for this situation, but probably the approach I would take.